# How can I monitor network connections for an app

Tags: linux, networking, process

I'm running a chat application on my machine called foo - how do I view all connection attempts (failed or successful) for foo?

I have attempted this with `netstat`, but I am unsure how to associate these connections with a specific application.

Comment: What operating system? Please add that information to your question, or at least add a tag. If Linux, then there are `iptables` rules you can use to count traffic originated by a particular *user*... but I can't think of a way to count by originating *application*.

Comment: @Celada or group, so you can adapt it by using a special group or user just for that application.

Answer (score 2):

you can use tcptrack

more info can be found at 
http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/dapper/man1/tcptrack.1.html

you'll find a detailed description of all connections and eventually select specific app connection

Comment: unfortunately, i still don't see way to associate this information with an application - just get back client (ip and port) server (ip and port) state (closed or established), idle time and speed